# How to create a SwiftUI List View with a large (all list) header view?

Tags: uitableview, swiftui, swiftui-list

I would like to create a `List` view in `SwiftUI` with has a large, header which has no paddings and extends into the safe area.

For example like in this screenshot:

[image]

Solving this in `UIKit` would not be problem. One could simply use the `tableViewHeader` of `UITableView` to achieve this. **But how can this be done in `SwiftUI` using a `List` view?**

While I found several examples on how to create **section headers**, I found nothing about a complete **table header**.

Of course one can simple add a subview to the list:

```
List {
    // Header
    Rectangle()
        .someStyling(...)

    // Items
    ForEach(myList, id: \.self) { element in
        Text(element)
    }
}
```

However, the same paddings, safe area insets, etc. which are applied to the list items are also applied to the header. Can this be avoided?

### Or is List not necessary?

I took this screenshot from [this YouTube](https://youtu.be/PQD6z0bNeHo) tutorial video. Unfortunately the tutorial does not show exactly what I am looking for. Instead of using a `List` to show large data set, it simply uses a `ScrollView` holding a `VStack` with an `Image` view (= the header) + a `ForEach` loop for the items.

Coming from `UIKit` and `UITableView` I have my doubts, that this is a good idea. Creating thousands of `UIViews` in a loop and stacking them would result in terrible performance. `UITableView` on the other hands re-uses view to create a much better performance.

**But is this also true for `List` vs. `VStack` in `SwiftUI`?**

Or is `ListView` just the same as a `VStack` and creating a large number of subviews in a loop is no problem here (e.g. because SwiftUI always only creates/draws the visible views)?

Answer (score 0):

The thing about **SwiftUI** creating only the visible views is only true for `LazyVStack`, not `VStack`.

For the header in the `List`, you can use `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))`. However, there would still be some spacing left.

You can use `.padding(.all, -20)` on the `List`, but then you would need to revert the padding on all of its elements. It’s a long shot, but could be worth it.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try. However, this solution is a bit hacky, since it relies on fixed correction values. If the default padding changes in iOS or maybe on different devices, this will be a problem. Is there really no "real" solution for this? I cannot believe that it is this difficult in SwiftUI while being no problem in UIKit.

Comment: When in need of a custom list I always use `LazyVStack`, it gives you a deeper control of the layout. As you said, It's best not to hack the framewok. Give it a try!